Max does not return maximum timestamp value
In PostgreSQL 16.1 I have a very large table mytable with a column _modified with type Timestamp with time zone. When I run below query on the whole table, it returns a lower timestamp value compared to when I run the query on as subset of the table.
A query on the whole table returns 06-11-2023 17:06:38.000:
select max(cast(_modified at time zone 'UTC' as timestamp))
from mytable 
;

A subset of the table returns 11-06-2023 17:06:38.001:
select max(cast(_modified at time zone 'UTC' as timestamp))
from mytable 
where mycondition = true
;

I would expect the query without where clause to return at least the value of a subset of the query. Not sure if it is related but I run these queries in DBeaver. Anyone any idea how this could happen and how to force the max operator to return the correct value?

You do realise that the 6th of November 2023 is higher than the 11th of June 2023, right? In other words, as currently shown, there seems to be no issue and the results are correct. Otherwise, provide a [mre] (and make sure it's correct and consistent).

06-11-2023 is ambiguous. Is this November 6 or June 11?

Apparently the date is formatted as dd-mm-yyyy and the expected result is correct.

Impossible to answer without data and timestamp configuration. But it looks like you don't have a problem at all, we're just missing the data to confirm this.

I think your queries works correctly, it's just that the format in which you get the result is dd-mm-yyyy.
Thus, the value in the entire table (06-11-2023) is greater than the value in the subset of rows (11-06-2023).

Try reindexing the table using:
REINDEX TABLE mytable

